# Confusion about "horizontal composition" of natural transformations

Tags: category-theory, abstract-algebra

I'm having trouble with an exercise from Rotman's Homological Algebra. It has to do with what Wikipedia calls "[horizontal composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Operations_with_natural_transformations)" of natural transformations. Namely, given $F, G:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ and $F^\prime, G^\prime:\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{C}$ covariant functors and $\sigma:F\to G$ and $\tau:F^\prime\to G^\prime$ natural transformations, the goal is to show that there is a composite natural transformation $\tau\sigma: F^\prime F\to G^\prime G$.

There should be a "natural choice" for the morphism $(\tau\sigma)_A$ associated to any $A\in\operatorname{obj}\mathcal{A}$, and this is where I'm confused. The problem says to define $$(\tau\sigma)_A=\tau_{FA}\sigma_A : F^\prime F(A)\to G^\prime G(A)$$ but this doesn't make sense to me since $\tau_{FA}\in\operatorname{Hom}(F^\prime F(A),G^\prime F(A))$ and $\sigma_A\in\operatorname{Hom}(FA,GA)$ (right?). It's not clear to me why this is the right composition, or that it even *is* a composition.

If I had to guess, I would say $(\tau\sigma)_A:=\tau_{GA}F^\prime(\sigma_A)$ because this is the only thing I can come up with that actually is a morphism $F^\prime F(A)\to G^\prime G(A)$.

Can anyone clear up my confusion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your guess is correct, but besides $\tau_{GA}\circ F'(\sigma_A)$, there is *another* natural choice, namely:
$$(\tau\sigma)_A=G'(\sigma_A)\circ \tau_{FA}\,,$$
and the point is that *they are equal*.

To be honest, I have no idea where the $\tau_{FA}\sigma_A$ could come from.. Might be a typo..

---

Note also that if we define natural transformations as functors $\mathcal A\to\mathcal B^\to$, where $\mathcal B^\to$ denotes the arrow category of $\mathcal B$ whose objects are the arrows of $\mathcal B$ and whose morphisms are commutative squares in $\mathcal B$, then we arrive to

> $(\tau\sigma)_A \ =\ $ the common composition of square $\tau(\sigma_A)$.

Comment: It might be worth adding that the reason $\tau_{GA}\circ F'(\sigma_A)= G'(\sigma_A)\circ \tau_{FA}$ is that this is naturality of $\tau$ on the morphism $\sigma_A \in \text{Hom}_{B}(FA, GA)$.